# Gtkmm label not successfully being inserted into a ListBox

Tags: c++, gtk3, gtkmm

From a Gtk::Builder I've retried a pointer to a Gtk::ListBox from a glade file, called `listbox_serverlist`.

Here is a minimal piece of code that I belive sums it up:

```
Gtk::ListBox* listbox_serverlist;
builder->get_widget("listbox_serverlist", listbox_serverlist);

Gtk::Label l;
l.set_text("Test");
listbox_serverlist->insert(l, -1)
```

Immediately after this, I run the main window, which the listbox is in.

My issue is that, although the listbox results in not being empty, there certainly isn't any text in it. I was hoping for my label to appear as an item in the list box, but instead there seems to be one selectable item, but it's completely blank.

Is there any code I must write to perhaps update the actual text in the label, or something to this effect?

I hope my question is clear, but I'd be happy to provide more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since "it works for me":

```
#include <gtkmm.h>

int main()
{
    auto Application = Gtk::Application::create();
    Gtk::Window window;
    Gtk::ListBox listbox;
    window.add(listbox);
    Gtk::Label label, label2;
    label.set_text("asdf");
    label2.set_text("qwer");
    listbox.add(label);
    listbox.insert(label2, -1);
    window.show_all();
    return Application->run(window);
}
```

[image]

my guess would be: are you using [Gtk::Widget::show_all()](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/3.20/classGtk_1_1Widget.html#a4fab2509c3afe1952a408494561295c0)? I have found that for some reason Gtk::Widget::show() was not enough for some hierarchies of widgets. Also I can't find it in [3.91 reference](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/3.91/classGtk_1_1Widget.html), so maybe that will change?

Comment: Thank you _so_ much! You are a life saver. I was missing the show_all() call. The project which I'm using this code for is due pretty soon, and as such if I could upvote this answer 100 times I would!

Answer (score 2):

You have to insert a [ListBoxRow](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkListBox.html#GtkListBoxRow) and then add the Label to the Row.

Alternatively, the [docs](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkListBox.html#GtkListBox.description) list [gtk_container_add()](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkContainer.html#gtk-container-add) as a solution.

**Edit**

I am not good at C++, but something like this should do the trick:

```
Gtk::ListBoxRow* list_box_row;
list_box_row.add(l); //add label widget to row
listbox_serverlist.add(list_box_row);  //add row to listbox
```

Comment: I'll test this out when I get to my desktop! Sounds hopeful

Comment: How do I add the label to the row? I can't find any documentation about ListBoxRow, and the header file listboxrow.h is hard to read.

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't seem to work. I can't find any Gtkmm (C++) documentation for the ListBoxRow, unfortunately, but I feel like if I could that would help a lot. Do you know of any?

Comment: You are right, the official Gtk documentation for ListBox in Gtkmm does not exist.

Comment: Maybe... https://fossies.org/linux/gtkmm/docs/reference/html/classGtk_1_1ListBoxRow.html

Comment: You may want to take a peek at this third party [example](https://github.com/GNOME/gtkmm-documentation/tree/master/examples/book/listbox).

Comment: none of this seems to be working :( Is there any trick to it, like updating the listbox once a row has been added, or perhaps do I have to add everything to the listbox _before_ adding the listbox to the window? Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I've found something in the documentation about a sort function. Do I need one of these for the insert and append functions to work?

Comment: Are you using gtk_show_all for sure at the end? See @pan-mroku [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54009170/6150775).

Comment: No, the sort feature is to sort your entries. For example, turn `B, A, C` to `A, B, C`.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else experiencing this issue, I recommend to add
`Gtk::manage(WIDGET);`

Example:

```
class MyListRow : public Gtk::ListBoxRow {
  private:
    Gtk::Label label;
    Gtk::Box box;

  public:
    MyListRow(char const *appID) {
        label.set_label(appID);
        box.pack_start(label, Gtk::PACK_START, 0);
        add(box);
        show_all();
        Gtk::manage(this);
    }
};
```

In main:

`listBox->append(*new MyListRow("title"));`